# String variable shared throughout different instance of classes

Tags: c++

I am using visual studio express 2013 and am new to C++ (whilst I do have a good understanding of Java this problem has me stumped).

The "text" variable in the "Dialogue" class seems to share the same value with it's other instances
What I mean by this is that both of the dialogue.Print()'s output"Then give it back!" in the console.

```
//Main Class
int main()
{
    Dialogue dialogue1("Okay...");
    Dialogue dialogue2("Then give it back!");

    dialogue1.Print();
    dialogue2.Print();
}
```

Note: These classes are seperate

```
//The "Dialogue Class"
#include "Dialogue.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string text;

Dialogue::Dialogue(string dialogue)
{
    text = dialogue;
}

Dialogue::~Dialogue()
{

}

void Dialogue::Print()
{
    cout << text << endl;
}
```

Comment: your code is writing out global variable twice...

Comment: `main` is not a class, it's a function. Unlike with java, functions and data can exist outside classes in C++ (in namespaces, and in your example in the global namespace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When coming from a Java background you have to consider that unlike in Java in C++ you can define things to exist outside of classes. So you can not only have static variables in classes (like in Java) but you can also have variables that are completely global or only associated with a namespace. As far as i know you can't do that in Java.
That what happens in your code. Your `std::string text` is defined not as member of your class Dialogue but outside of it, so it's basically a global variable so you are right it only exists once and not per Dialog instance. If you move into your class definition of Dialogue (dialogue.h) it will work as you expect.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it was incredibly helpful. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You define text as a global variable.

```
string text;
```

So the same variable is used again and again.

Define it as member variable in the class definition (I suppose in dialogue.h):

```
class Dialogue { 
...
    string text;
...
};
```